# Click on the x in the SelectPicker element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-selectpicker

```
var selectedTags = [];
var selectedTags2 = [];

if (d && d.length) {

  d.forEach(function(value, index, array) {

    if (index < 5) {
      var color = $('option[value="' + value + '"]').data('color');
      var tagSpan = '<span class="label label-' + color + '" style="margin-right:1px;"><span class="icon icon-times">' + value + '</span></span>';
      selectedTags.push(tagSpan);
      list = [];
      c = 1;
    } else {
      var color2 = $('option[value="' + value + '"]').data('color');
      var tagSpan2 = '<span class="label label-' + color2 + '" style="margin-right:1px;"><span class="icon icon-times">' + value + '</span></span>';
      selectedTags2.push(tagSpan2);
      list.push(tagSpan2);
    }
  });
}

var allTagsElement = selectedTags.join('');

if (a <= 0) {
  return "<div class='col-md-11 col-xs-10' style='padding-left:0px;'> " + allTagsElement + " </div><div class='col-md-1 col-xs-2'id='eSecim'></div>";
}

return "<div class='col-md-10 col-xs-10' style='padding-left:0px;'> " + allTagsElement + " </div><div class='col-md-1 col-xs-2'id='eSecim'>+" + (-a) + "</div>";
```

I want to get out of here.

I use the bootstrap selectpicker. I will select it by clicking on the x next to the elements.

[image]

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking post the whole code and be more explicit please !

Comment: Its not very clear what the question. Please put more description.

Comment: "I want to get out of here.". No idea what you mean by that. Out of where? And to where else? And why? We're not mind-readers, you'll have to give some proper detail.